# Mixer Audio output xlr small contact with pin power suply of guitar pedals , possible damages?

Tags: power-supply, power-engineering, circuit-protection, electricity, electrical

Last night after a gig my audio Mixer output cables has had a small contact with the pin of the power supply of my guitar pedals that was on electricity.

The mixer was not on electricity but the VU meters of the mixer detected the contact.

The mixer is working normally, but may have caused damages to the mixer this small contact of the mixer audio output with the power suply of the pedal (12V), (i have put a picture of how was the contact) ?

I am very aware of this because I use this mixer for gigs and would not want it to fail during live performance.[image][image]

Comment: Part of the answer is going to be in the question, who built the mixer? If it's a professional product it's built to take a lot of abuse, like transformer coupled (balanced and fully isolated ) inputs and outputs; if it's a cheap product, not so much. But a professional product is unlikely to have RCA jacks...

Comment: @BrianDrummond -- tell that to the Mackie mixer I used to work with -- it had a set of RCA I/Os for interfacing to things like CD players.

Comment: I said "unlikely", not "impossible". Mackie sure, Neve maybe not so much.

Comment: The connector you show is an RCA Phono connector, not an XLR.

Comment: Yes my mistake, the contact was between rca but mtge mixer has balanced XLR main output and rca in case you need unbalanced , i use the RCA to record the gig.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely that PSU has no reference to ground. You can confirm this by checking the mains cable. An oval / flat cable or two-pin plug or plastic earth pin (depending on country) indicates that there is no earth connection.

If this is the case the power-plug is similar to a battery. It is floating with respect to ground and touching one point of it to another circuit will do nothing as no (significant) current will flow.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flQwgA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Various power-in scenarios.*

- In (a) the battery negative has been connected to the input. Since the positive is not connected no current can flow.
- In (b) the battery positive has been connected to the input. Since negative is not connected no current can flow.
- In (c) there is a complete circuit so DC will be applied to the circuit. Even in this condition 12 V is unlikely to cause any damage as the input capacitors will block the voltage after the initial transient.

The flick on the VU meters is probably due to some capacitance between your power-supply and ground. I would not be concerned about damage.

Comment: Hi , thanks for answering, i will update the photo of the post with the power supply and the type of cable it has ! What made me afraid of any possible damage that the VU meters reached the maksimum , the contact was for something like  4sec till i understood in the midle of 100 cable that was the contact of the line out with the pedal power supply that couses this !

Comment: Don't bother. It was probably mains hum coming in on the audio line. Mic and line inputs are sensitive to 10 mV to 1 V or so.

Comment: Ok , i am a but more chilled now , thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Just one thing , the contact was with the unbalanced master output of the mixer not with the inputs , is the same logic also in this case ?

Comment: Yes, but it's more of a surprise that the VU meters sensed it.